# SNS X axis plot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am trying to plot a scatter plot with Seaborn but it is messing with the X axis somehow:

[image: Dataframe:]

Seaborn call:

```
    sns.scatterplot(x=range(len(df_distr)),y='predict', data=df_distr)
```

Output:
[image: ScatterPlot]

Comment: Just set x="ylin_test" instead of using the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should do it:

```
 sns.scatterplot(x='ylin_test',y='predict', data=df_distr)
```